# Check result value and add String AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am fetching a number (percentage) from a service and want to display it in a proper way with the percentage sign behind the number. In some cases the service returns 'N/A' if the number isn´t aviable so I can´t hardcode the `%` in my html due to the fact that it would result 'N/A'% in the final page.

So the question which comes up to me is:

**How can I check wether my result is a number so I can add a `char`/`string` in in a simple way directly in the HTML code or do I have to check the returned value of my service in the controller/JS-code ?**

I tried something like this but it doesn't work due to an error message with unexpected chars.

```
Average User Rating:</b> {{ user.Rating=='N/A' ? 'N/A' : user.Rating '%'}} <br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More reusable solution:

```js
app.filter('percentizer', function(){
        return function(value){
            if (!isNaN(value)) return value + "%";
            else return value;
        }
    });
```

```html
{{user.Rating | percentizer}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `+` sign:

`{{ user.Rating=='N/A' ? 'N/A' : user.Rating + '%'}}`